# How to use a PostScript Type 1 or TrueType font file in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, fonts

iOS doesn't have a font that I want to use. Is there a way to include my own font in my iOS app? FYI it's a TeX font.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can embed custom fonts as of iOS 3.2. See the UIAppFonts info plist key http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18

Note that the system only loads true type (ttf) and open type (otf) formats. You would have to convert your TeX font to one of these formats.